# How to set validation for HH:MM time format?

Tags: c#, time

I am doing an updation. So I have set value from database to a text box in time format like HH:MM

```
 00:00
 if I enter 8:00//it should show error
 if I enter 08:0//it should show error
```

How can I perform this???. Entering this value in a text box. Ajax code also acceptable. it is a web application form and it is in a 24 hours format also.

Comment: What is the application forms or web ?

Comment: @Coder of Code, its a web application form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RegularExpressionValidator` and below `ValidationExpression`.

```
  ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$"
```

Here is more info on how to use the [RegularExpressionValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Is your hours format is going to depend on the user like some might use it 12 or some use it for 24 hours ? If that's the case then let me know that might need different approch

Comment: I done it with small changes like this  "^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"

Comment: Check the update that will give you with `AM/PM` option 24 hour format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` method

```
String a = "08:0"; // text as string 

DateTime time= new DateTime(); // Passed result if succeed 

 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(a, "hh:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out time)) {
    Console.WriteLine("pass");
 }
 else {
    Console.WriteLine("fail");
 }
```

Note : hh for 12 hour format, use HH for 24 hour format

Answer (score 0):

```
Dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (Dr.Read())
{
    txtReguID.Text = Dr["Registration_ID"].ToString();
    string addmissiondate = Dr["AdmissionDate"].ToString();

    txtAdmissionDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(addmissiondate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```